# Single type parameter T should have a trailing comma. Example usage: <T,>

Tags: typescript, npm, eslint

Single type parameter T should have a trailing comma. Example usage: <T,>. (3:29)

```
export const toggleItem = <T>(
```

How to turn of this error? If I add a <T,> prettier removes the "," on save.
I have no change in the package.json, have deleted node_modules and package-lock.json file.
Hope somebody can point me in the right direction to what I can do to fix this?

Node v16.14.1
NPM 8.5.4

```
"@babel/core": "7.14.3",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.13.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "7.14.4",
"@babel/preset-react": "7.13.13",
"@babel/preset-typescript": "7.13.0",
"@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop": "11.2.0",
"@emotion/eslint-plugin": "11.2.0",
"@types/hammerjs": "2.0.39",
"@types/node": "15.6.1",
"@types/page": "1.11.2",
"@types/react": "17.0.9",
"@types/react-datepicker": "4.3.4",
"@types/react-dom": "17.0.6",
"@types/signalr": "2.2.36",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.26.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.26.0",
"eslint": "7.27.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
"eslint-plugin-filenames": "1.3.2",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.23.4",
"eslint-plugin-node": "11.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-normatic": "file:eslint",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.4.0",
"eslint-plugin-promise": "5.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "7.24.0",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.2.0",
"eslint-rule-composer": "0.3.0",
```

Comment: You only need those trailing commas on type parameters in `.tsx` files, and [as of this PR](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/6115) from three years ago, Prettier understands that and leaves them in place. Perhaps you're not using a `.tsx` extension? (You should, for TypeScript code with JSX in it.)

Comment: Yes, it is a util.ts file. It contains 

export const toggleItem = <T>(
  item: T,
  items: T[],
  predicate?: (a: T, b: T) => boolean
) => {
  const current = [...items]
  const index = predicate
    ? items.findIndex((b) => predicate(item, b))
    : items.indexOf(item)
  if (index !== -1) {
    current.splice(index, 1)
  } else {
    current.push(item)
  }
  return current
}

This code has work for 1year. I'm new to JS and tsx, but if I change the extension to tsx it get ugly all over the code :(

Comment: You don't need the trailing comma if you're not writing TSX (TypeScript + JSX). You *do* need it if you are. And if you are, you need to tell your tools that you are by using the correct file extension: `.tsx`. If that reveals other errors in your code, then you need to fix those other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to T.J.Crowder for help. I change the file extension to .jsx and change the function to use "ANY" and not the "T".

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem here and I don't think this should be a tsx file as it does not contain any JSX...

edit: Guess I found the relevant issue on github: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/14361

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).